# Active Storage appears to be looking for an attached file instead of attaching them

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

When I make a post request with a photo in it to a controller for a model that has a photo attached through activestorage but am receiving a #<ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: Failed to save the new associated photo_attachment.>

Code is in the following gist for readability, please let me know if i should break it down and put it in this post more directly.

https://gist.github.com/njmbb8/0042e47a5427606da70727de9dd6617d

Answer (score 0):

i had commented out `config.active_storage.service = :local` in config/environments/development.rb